# Run through array of strings and find a match in url, how to do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to figure out how to find a string from array in url of the page. I know how to find a string from similar answers but I am not getting to run through an array, something like this has been done:

url e.g: http://www.sitename.com/the-window-is-open

```
var stringToFind = [
            'book',
            'window',
            'cup'
        ];

if(window.location.href.indexOf(stringToFind) > -1) {
    console.log("your url contains "+stringToFind);
}
```

Do I have to use "for" loop or maybe there is much simpler way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not a valid object, did you actually intend to use an array ?

Comment: @adeneo just about to write that -> +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `stringToFind` variable to array like:

```
var stringToFind = ['book', 'window', 'cup'];
```

and then you can use the native js `for` loop like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stringToFind.length; i++) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(stringToFind[i]) > -1) {
        console.log("your url contains " + stringToFind[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, does it have an advantage over jQuery version?

Comment: Yes, native js is always faster than jQuery each loop. Also, there's no requirement to include the jQuery file here just for the loop purpose, in case you not already using it.

Comment: in most javascript implementations you can also use the native `.forEach` and not need jQuery: `stringToFind.forEach( function(s) { 
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(s) > -1) {
        console.log("your url contains " + s);
    }`

Comment: Wanted to ask If indexOf(stringToFind[i]) > -1 is going find plurals or an exact match. For example I see that it detects WINDOWS and WINDOW as the same thing. Do you know how to avoid that? Thanks, your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jquery each:

```
var stringToFind = [
            'book',
            'window',
            'cup'
        ];

    $.each(stringToFind, function(index, element){
        if(window.location.href.indexOf(element) > -1) {
            console.log("your url contains "+ element);
        }
    })
```

Note that stringToFind must be an array, not an object.

Comment: thank you, looks nice although jQuery was not required unless you say with jQuery this is much more faster o has any other advantage?

Comment: @devjs11 jquery is not required, you could do it with a standard for loop, but I like this version more. It's more readable and you don't need to have an extra indexing variable in the scope.